# changes are not reflected in UI in react but values are updating when i console log

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set state and i could see values are reflecting when i console log it but in UI changes are not reflecting

is it correct way to set state using hooks

```js
const [items, setItems]= React.useState({'tab1':[],'tab2':[],'tab3':[]})

const oldData = [{id:'1',name:'tom'},
              {id:'2',name:'kel'},
              {id:'3',name:'clony'},
              {id:'4',name:'jim'}]

const updateItems = (data)=> {
  const copy = {...data};
  copy['tab1'] = [...oldData]
  return copy;
}
setItems((prevData)=> {
  return updateItems(prevData)
})
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setItems` in your code? Please provide all the relevant code. Also you are updating a key `'1'` in `updateItems` but your initial state has keys like `'tab1'`...

Comment: Please provide the code as you have it in your app so we can reproduce the issue. You can of course strip the irrelevant lines but we need to see the components involved. The code as you present it does not help finding out why your UI doesn't update.